# Call by value in C

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm new to programming and I am currently working on C.

I learned that C does not have call by reference. The programs that we write to pass the address of actual parameters to the formal parameters is also call by Value in C.

Correct me if I'm wrong.. However, I ran this program :

//Swapping of two numbers using functions.
    #include

```
void swap(int *,int *);

void main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf ("Enter the values of x and y : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

    swap(x,y);

    printf("The value of x = %d and y = %d",x,y);
}

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int temp;

    temp=*b;
    *b=*a;
    *a=temp;
}
```

It compiles just fine.. however, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault in the Output.

It asks me the enter the value of X and Y and then gives, Segmentation fault..

Please help!!

Comment: You should pass `swap(&x,&y)` to pass the address of these variables.

Comment: It won't compile just find if you enable all warnings & debug info. With `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you *will* get warnings that you should take care of.

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Comment: This code isn't valid C. If it compiled then something is seriously wrong with your compiler. You have to find out if it is incorrectly configured or alternatively switch to a better one.

Comment: All the answers have clearly pointed out what the issue with your function was. But I would like to add that the parameters are still being passed by value. It is the address of the variables that is passed by value. *C has no pass by reference*.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya From the caller's point-of-view only:  `void foo(int *x); int x[1]; foo(x);`  how would this differ from _pass by reference_ of `x`?  Code passes `x`, `foo()` can change the contents of `x`.

Answer (score 7):

you are sending an `int` to a function that expects `int*`, thus when you are dereferencing - `temp=*b;` you are trying to access memory you don't own -> segfault. Call `swap` like this: `swap(&x,&y);`

Answer (score 5):

So close

```
swap(&x,&y);
```

You were not passing references (pointers)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid similar segfaults at runtime, always compile with `-Wall`.

Actually, there is a way to pass-by-reference in C, just change two lines in your code like this:

```
#define swap(x,y)  swap_impl__(&(x), &(y))

static void swap_impl__(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*b;
    *b=*a;
    *a=temp;
}

void main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf ("Enter the values of x and y : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

    swap(x,y);

    printf("The value of x = %d and y = %d",x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the call by value method of passing arguments to a function copies the actual value of an argument into the formal parameter of the function. In this case, changes made to the parameter inside the function have no effect on the argument.
but here you are passing values

```
swap(x,y)
```

but taking it as address

`void swap(int *a,int *b)`

so it is looking for an address which passed by your variable.
for example, if you have passed something like

`swap(x,y)`

and 
if `we have x=100 and y=200`,  then it is assuming 100 and 200 to be addresses
and trying to access it will definitely give you error as they may not exist or having garbage value.